# Camel The application attempted to use a JMS session after it had closed the session

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I am new to camel and I am attempting to write an app that bridges Websphere MQ and Active MQ on JBoss EAP 7.  The app deploys successfully works, I can drop messages on the Websphere queue, and it gets picked up by Active MQ.  However I see error messages in the log showing it is attempting to use a connection after it is open.

```
15:48:57,814 ERROR [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (Camel (camel) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[I0_TEST]) IJ000315: Pool IbmMQQueueFactory has 1 active handles
15:48:57,819 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (Camel (camel) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[I0_TEST]) wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4016:Unregistered connection handle being closed: 'com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionWrapper@214da401'.
15:49:02,819 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] (Camel (camel) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[I0_TEST]) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'I0_TEST' - trying to recover. Cause: Local JMS transaction failed to commit; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: MQJCA1020: The session is closed.
The application attempted to use a JMS session after it had closed the session.
Modify the application so that it closes the JMS session only after it has finished using the session.
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/ConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="wmqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/jms/IbmMQMsgQCF" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="wmqTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="wmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="wmqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="wmqTransactionManager" />
</bean>


<bean id="routerlogger" class="org.jboss.as.quickstarts.mdb.RoutLogger" />

<camelContext trace="true" id="camel"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route>
        <from uri="wmq:websphereQueue"/>
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/>
        <to uri="jms:activeQueue" pattern="InOnly" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Its a simple app, trying to determine what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this JBossDeveloper bug "[JBEAP-2344: UserTransaction commit(), rollback() closes connection in Websphere MQ 7.5](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-2344)" which looks like it describes your issue and has comments pointing to documentation update "[JBEAP-3535: Documentation: Add note about connection close on commit() and rollback() to Deploy the WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter subchapter](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-3535)".

> Could you please add a note, that setting `tracking="false"`, solves
>   problem with WebSphere MQ 7.5 and 8, where method commit() or
>   rollback() on UserTransaction closes any JMS connections which was
>   part of this transaction. This part is related to documenting known
>   limitation of WebSphere MQ in
>   [JBEAP-3142](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-3142).

Comment: I'm trying to relate this to configuring MQ in IBM Liberty where I'm getting the same error. Is there a page that describes "tracking=false" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363362/camel-transacted-mq-session-closed-on-every-commit