# Camel Transacted: MQ Session closed on every commit

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq

I have:

- Camel route (transacted=true), consuming from an MQ Queue
- Using Spring's WebSphereUowTransactionManager
- Transactionality works
- Running on IBM Liberty

But, I get this message:

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'MY.QUEUE' - trying to recover. 
Cause: Local JMS transaction failed to commit; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: 
MQJCA1020: The session is closed.
The application attempted to use a JMS session after it had closed the session.
Modify the application so that it closes the JMS session only after it has finished using the session.
```

This appears to be related to this [other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058373/camel-the-application-attempted-to-use-a-jms-session-after-it-had-closed-the-ses), but I've tried changing the configuration in server.xml, with no success.

Comment: You can try setting cacheLevelName=CACHE_CONSUMER.

Comment: Darius, any feed back on Claus Ibsen's suggestion?  Can you show your full camel route?

Comment: @JoshMc, Yes, I just tried it and it worked.  I had used CACHE_NONE because I did not know if transactions would work right with the other options (I am using Spring's WebSphereUowTransactionManager)

Comment: @ClausIbsen should write a answer up that you can accept and reward the bounty too.

Comment: An update: we actually could not get Transactions to work right with CACHE_CONSUMER, and so, switched back to CACHE_NONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting `cacheLevelName=CACHE_CONSUMER` which allows to re-use the JMS consumer and avoids endless of creation/destruction of JMS resources, as indicated by the error message may be the cause.

You can see more about the importanse of cache levels on the Camel JMS documentation: http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: It's worth noting that while CACHE_CONSUMER answers this question for normal non-error conditions, I encountered a situation where when using transactions and CACHE_CONSUMER and an exception was thrown in the consumer, the listener seemed to just stop listening: no no other queue messages would be consumed.  Changing to CACHE_CONNECTION seemed to solve this such that the consumer kept running after an error.  I don't know though what you lose during regular non-error conditions by using CACHE_CONNECTION instead of CACHE_CONSUMER.